# C# code for getting Google user profile information from google API

Tags: c#, api

I've got my access token of google plus, I want to get my profile information such as name, email, gender, and ID. What c# code should I do, I able to retrieve my contacts but I got an issue to retrieving login user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find them here as assets https://developers.google.com/unity/ or check in unity's asset store there are many assets to help you

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=google

Comment: Actually I've access token, through that access token I want my google user information, can you please suggest me c# code for it.

Comment: When you add the asset to the project it comes with the libraries you need to make it work.
The key you get from google is used so you can identify yourself with google and thus use the asset in unity.
Now about the code you just need to check what do you need to get from googleplay **remember it won't show in your computer you have to test your code in a cellphone to make it work**

on the github website you'll find initialization variables and examples in the asset that may be of help, explore them and check the codes they include so you can add them to your game objects.

Comment: You might find this video usefull I go a lot to youtube to find tutorials and how to
https://youtu.be/XmHXl-UFTqM
also check this asset out, it might help you
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/43736

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links will help you. Go through this links. Don't fully rely on what is said there. Use this link as help for your own try. Best of Luck

https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/csharp

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/85569312-509d-423b-9993-8fe3574fc369/how-to-use-google-api-after-i-get-token?forum=winappswithcsharp